# Embedding Multiple Images In Outlook 2010 via Access 2010 VBA

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

Code (and solution) to be in MS Access VBA.

I want a header and footer logo and three images within the text of my email. (This is a simplistic get-it-working code. The final will be customized for each email)

If I uncomment any of the five commented lines the relevant image is displayed and the REST of the text shows.

i.e. I get only one image and whatever remaining text ~ I don't get five images interspersed with text.

The style section does not seem to work either ~ the footer remains in Times New Roman size 12 :-(

Here is what I have so far. Uncomment any of the lines to see the problem. Ideal is to uncomment them all and see 5 images at the receiving end of the email.

NB the five images are on my laptop (c:\images\ various pictures ).  I do not want a solution to point to a server location for the images, I just want to embed and send a self-contained email.

```
Const MyPath = "C:\images\"
Const MyPicture1 = "Picture1.jpg"
Const mypicture2 = "Picture2.jpg"
Const mypicture3 = "Picture3.jpg"
Const mypicture4 = "Picture4.jpg"
Const mypicture5 = "Picture5.jpg"

Dim str_head, str_style, str_body, str_body_end, str_text As String

With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & MyPicture1
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & mypicture2
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & mypicture3
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & mypicture4
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & mypicture5

    str_head = "<html> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-?jpe' content=' text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"

    str_style = "<style type='text/CSS'>" & vbCrLf & _
                "<!--" & vbCrLf & _
                "body { background-color: palegreen; } " & vbCrLf & _
                "h1 { margin: 1cm; font—size:14px; font—family: 'Times New Roman'; } " & vbCrLf & _
                "p.footer {margin: 1cm; font-size: 8px; font—family: 'Calibri'; } " & vbCrLf & _
                "-->" & vbCrLf & _
                "</style>"

    str_body = "</head> <body>"

    'str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(MyPicture1, " ", "%20") & " height=60 width=640>"    'Header logo

    str_text = str_text & "<h1>This is header text size 14 Times New Roman</h1>"

    str_text = str_text & "<p>This is body text size 12 Times New Roman</p>"

    'str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture2, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>"    'In text image

    str_text = str_text & "<p>This is more body text size 12 Times New Roman</p>"

    'str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture3, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>"    'In text image

    str_text = str_text & "<p>This is more body text size 12 Times New Roman</p>"

    'str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture4, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>"    'In text image

    str_text = str_text & "<p class 'footer'>This is footer text size 8 Calibri</p>"

    'str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture5, " ", "%20") & " height=60 width=640>"       'Footer logo

    str_body_end = "</body> </html>"

    .HTMLBody = str_head & str_style & str_body & str_text & str_body_end
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a "str_text &" in your str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture2, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>" statement? (e.g.,  str_text = str_text & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture2, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>")

Comment: @billyhoes: Note that you can use `backticks` in comments too to make code readable. -- But yes, that would seem to be the problem, `str_text` is always overwritten from scratch. I suggest posting it as answer.

Comment: Similar error in style, line should read; str_text = str_text & "<p class='footer'>This is footer text size 8 Calibri</p>"  all working now! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing `str_text &` in your `str_text = "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture2, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>"` statement.  You are overwriting the str_text variable every time you add the image code to it.

Statements adding images should read like below:

```
str_text = str_text & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(mypicture1, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>")
```

Comment: Thank you Billy, you are quite correct, a schoolboy error which I made worst by cut-and-pasting the line four more times.  Your line is totally correct and works as I expected, thank you.

Comment: The style line

"p.footer {margin: 1cm; font-size: 8px; font—family: 'Calibri'; } " & vbCrLf & _

does not work as the email text remains Times 12 but the core question is resolved.  Brilliant.

Comment: We've all been there. Glad I could help.  :)